# Apex chart Area graph

Tags: frontend, chart.js, apexcharts

I am creating an area graph with ApexCharts. Basically, it is a stocks price chart. I want that if price goes down, graph at that point should become red and if goes up it should be green.

The data series i am using is like this -
series : [{
name: "price",
data: [110,200,109,90,89,400]
}]
. At 110 it should be red ,at 200 it should be green,at 109 it should become red as price dropped.